# Joining multiple records into one with PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a table with the following structure in SQL Server 2005:

```
ID    Day     DayDate    TimeEntry  TimeOut   Rest     Monday
1   Monday   17-06-2013   08:00      18:00    14:30   17-06-2013
2   Tuesday  18-06-2013   08:00      18:00    14:30   17-06-2013
```

So on until week Monday field allows me to group all the days of a given week.

Now I need to gather the data in one record in a view:

```
Id DayDateMonday TimeEntryMonday TimeOutMonday RestMonday 
   DayDateTuesday TimeEntryTuesday TimeOutTuesday RestTuesday .... so on.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is support for the PIVOT clause in SQL Server 2005 and above, it may be better to pivot the data manually in your situation, i.e. with the help of grouping and conditional aggregation.

One note, though: `Id`, if it is meant to be the `ID` column from the original table, would make no sense in your view. Every single day has its own ID and your view gathers several days in one row, so there doesn't seem to be any point in putting a single `ID` there. For the purpose of this answer, therefore, I'm replacing it with the date of the week's Monday (the `Monday` column, renamed to `WeekDate` for the output).

Other than that, here's your good old "manual" pivot:

```
SELECT
  WeekDate = Monday,

  DayDateMonday   = MAX(CASE Day WHEN 'Monday' THEN DayDate   END),
  TimeEntryMonday = MAX(CASE Day WHEN 'Monday' THEN TimeEntry END),
  TimeOutMonday   = MAX(CASE Day WHEN 'Monday' THEN TimeOut   END),
  RestMonday      = MAX(CASE Day WHEN 'Monday' THEN Rest      END),

  DayDateTuesday   = MAX(CASE Day WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN DayDate   END),
  TimeEntryTuesday = ...  -- and so on

FROM timetable
GROUP BY
  Monday
;
```